# Vue 3 scoped style affecting children by copying parent 'data-v-x' attribute

Tags: css, vuejs3

For some reason Vue3 will copy the scoped style unique attribute ('data-v') to the immediate child element of the child control.

This can be observed [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

In the example I have 3 components (Comp1-3) which all have the scoped style and the same class name. You can observe that Comp1 css affects immediate child (Comp2) while the Comp2 affects immediate child (Comp3). If the components are outside of their affecting parent then its style is correct.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: *With scoped, the parent component's styles will not leak into child components. **However, a child component's root node will be affected by both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS. This is by design** so that the parent can style the child root element for layout purposes.* [Child Component Root Elements](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bravo's comment states the behavior is intentional. A way to avoid this is:

1. Use BEM or some other syntax to avoid accidentally having the same class name
2. Have two root elements (adding a Vue empty `<Fragment/>` should work as well). Note: with multiple roots Vue will no longer propagate any attributes (except props).
3. I have not tried it but I assume disabling attribute inheritance will also do the trick (https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance).